# get the value without ' '

Tags: python, list, finance

Hi what I want to do is this.

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes

def live_price(symbol):
    price = getQuotes(symbol)[0].values()[3]
    print price
```

If I run this, it will give me a price of a certain stock I entered in the func of live_price. But I want to do some calculation like this:

```
live_price('A')+live_price('B')
```

But since `print` does not give me the price as an "output" I cannot use those numbers for calculating something.

So I tried just `price` instead of `print price` at the last line.
Then it gives me the price of a certain stock as an output so that I can use it for calculating. But the thing is that the number is a string, it will not calculate properly.

What should I do to pull the price as an output so that I can use the number to compute things that I want to calculate?

Comment: return the value with, uhm, `return price` ?

Comment: And wrap price in float, as in `return float(price)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have a `'string'`. You want a number, so convert it to a `float` or [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
In [1]: my_str = '1.35'

In [2]: my_str_as_a_number = float(my_str)

In [3]: my_str_as_a_number
Out[3]: 1.35

In [4]: my_str_as_a_number + 1
Out[4]: 2.35
```

`float` is built-in, but if you want `Decimal` you need to import it first.

```
In [5]: from decimal import Decimal

In [6]: my_str_as_a_decimal = Decimal(my_str)

In [7]: my_str_as_a_decimal + 1
Out[7]: Decimal('2.35')
```

You can convert `Decimal` to `float` as well.

```
In [8]: float(_)
Out[8]: 2.35
```

The advantage of using Decimals over using floating point is that Decimals avoid some common [gotchas](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) caused by floating point representation's inexact nature.

Comment: Good reference, but I am really interested in knowing what advantages are there. Could you give some examples or point to some of them in the page/book you referenced?

Comment: Check out the first link to the official [Python decimal documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). It condenses the benefits down to several bullet points and is generally more readable and concise @RaduIonescu

Comment: This is much easier to understand than the cookbook of floating point arithmetic before :)

Comment: @MinjunKim Great! You can hit the green checkmark under the voting arrows to signal this is the answer that helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

use float and return price instead of printing.

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes

def live_price(symbol):
     price = getQuotes(symbol)[0].values()[3]
     return float(price)

x = live_price('A')+live_price('B')
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform the string to a real value with

```
return float(price)
```

Comment: @MinjunKim don't forget to click the check box near Two-Bit Alchemist score to accept his answer :)